# How can I fix the error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $get is not defined?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm trying to put different markers on a googlemaps map, by accessing some value of latitude and longitude that are specified on a database.

```
    var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 39.397, lng: -8 },
                zoom: 7
            });


            $get("@Url.Action("GetAllLocation", "Home")", function (data, '''status) {
                var marker = [];
                var contentString = [];
                var infowindow = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
                    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        //a posição será de acordo com que é recebido pelo '''android
                        position: { lat: data[i].Latitude, lng: '''data[i].Longitude },
                        map: map
                    });


                 contentString[i] = '<div id="content">' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                     '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                     '<p>Dispositivo:'+ data[i].Dispositivo+'</p>'+
                     '<p>Fotografias:</p>' +
                     '<p>Avaliação:</p>' +
                     '<p>Data:'+ data[i].DataOcorrencia+'</p>' +
                '</div>';

                    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString[i]
                });

                marker[i].addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow[i].open(map, marker);

                });
            }



        })






    }

    </script>


</div>
```

I just need to get the latitude and the longitude that I have specified on my database and for it to show on the map with its respective markers.

Comment: By making sure $get is actually a valid declaration? I.e. I'm guessing this is an ajax request and you're using jQuery, in which case it's `$.get` (note the period)

Comment: Should that be `$.get`?

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you. The error is not showing anymore. But the markers still don't show up on the map

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some syntax errors here (or some bad code paste), try this:

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: { lat: data[i].Latitude, lng: data[i]. Longitude },
         map: map
     });
markers.push(marker);
```

Obviously the Longitude property is misspelled and there are some extra quotes not needed.